# Translate OpenGL FFP to PP

Tags: ios, opengl, opengl-es

I am learning and translating some very old fixed function OpenGL (on desktop) into modern OpenGL (iOS). I have translated all of the verts, colors, and texturing but am stuck on these two lines and how to incorporate them into the modern architecture:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE_EXT);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_RGB_SCALE_EXT, 2.0f);
```

I believe the second is just scaling the RGB by 2 and clamping them [0,1]. But am not sure what exactly that means, would that be in the shader and is referring to the vertex color and texture color?

I am not sure what the first one does.

How and where would I put the translation of these, or achieve similar effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE)
```

enables "combining" the fragment color calculated by lighting or whatever at the vertex stage with the texel color. It's a fancier form of the old replace/modulate/decal modes. There should be one or two subsequent lines

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB|GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, ...
```

which specify the actual operation, which as well as replace/modulate could include dot products or interpolation.

The red book (OpenGL Programming Guide) includes a section on texture combiners at least up to the 6th edition.

You are correct that the second just multiples the RGB.

Both of these are texturing operations, so would be implemented in your fragment shader.

Hope this helps.